# Trying to retrieving data from firebase to my php project but it's always return null

Tags: php, firebase

I try to retrieving data from my firebase using kreait php but it's always return NULL even though the data is exist in my firebase database.

here is my firebase
[image]

here is my code

**connection.php**

```
<?php

require __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';

use Kreait\Firebase\Factory;

$factory = (new Factory)->withServiceAccount('./includes/secret/db-wind-2ceca-672d70f2f4a8.json')->withDatabaseUri('https://db-wind-2ceca-default-rtdb.asia-southeast1.firebasedatabase.app');

$auth = $factory->createAuth();
$database = $factory->createDatabase();

?>
```

**home.php**

```
  <?php
  session_start();
  if($_SESSION['user'] == false) {
    header('Location:index.php');
  }
  set_include_path(__DIR__);
  require('includes/koneksi.php');

  $reference = $database->getReference('db-wind-2ceca-default-rtdb/Crosswind1/');
  $value     = $reference->getValue();
  var_dump($value);die; // return: null
  ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `db-wind-2ceca-default-rtdb/` prefix from your `getReference()` call and it should work. That's the name of the database, which is already set through the `withDatabaseUri()` call.

Comment: Already did this. but it still returns null.

Answer (score 0):

well done bro, actually I have never used firebase in a php project. But i'll try to help.

I think you should modify in your connection.php

from this

```
require __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';

use Kreait\Firebase\Factory;

$factory = (new Factory)->withServiceAccount('./includes/secret/db-wind-2ceca-672d70f2f4a8.json')->withDatabaseUri('https://db-wind-2ceca-default-rtdb.asia-southeast1.firebasedatabase.app');

$auth = $factory->createAuth();
$database = $factory->createDatabase();
```

to this

```
require __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';

use Kreait\Firebase\Factory;
use Kreait\Firebase\ServiceAccount;

$serviceAccount = ServiceAccount::fromJsonFile(__DIR__ . '/includes/secret/db-wind-2ceca-672d70f2f4a8.json');

$factory = (new Factory)->withServiceAccount($serviceAccount)->withDatabaseUri('https://db-wind-2ceca-default-rtdb.asia-southeast1.firebasedatabase.app')->create();

$database = $factory->getDatabase();
```

Comment: It gives an error _Call to private method Kreait\Firebase\ServiceAccount::fromJsonFile()_. btw i use kreait version 5.17 my code is worked fine when i try like login feature with firebase but it somehow return null when i'm try to make retrieving data from firebase database.

Comment: Try this
$reference = $database->getReference('db-wind-2ceca-default-rtdb/Crosswind1/');
$snapshot = $reference->getSnapshot();
$value     = $snapshot->getValue();
var_dump($value);die; // return: null